# Local IIS & IIS Express hang while serving content files (JS & CSS)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-express

On a brand new installation of Windows 7 with IIS 7.5 and Visual Studio 2013 Express, IIS and IIS Express seem to hang while serving basic content files.

The content is very simple. It consists of:

- index.html (356 bytes)
- cssTest.css (1,122 bytes)
- jsTest.js (274,370 bytes)

Depending on the size of the file (but not the content), and whether I'm using Local IIS or IIS Express, browsers will freeze while downloading the content files linked to from index.html.

[image: Internet Explorer 11 hanging on download]

I've made additional screenshots and source code available at http://goo.gl/18cTrp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was being caused by [image: IIS Compression Icon] Compression.

In IIS, if I turned off compression, the error would cease to occur.

[image: Disabling Compression]

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with IIS (up to version 8.5). If you want to keep static compression (as it speeds up download times) then:

- Follow [instructions in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467543/9328747) to change settings for hit frequency checking
- Disable hit frequency checking completely (on IIS 8.5) with this command:

  ```
  %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency:"True"  /commit:apphost
  ```